# use array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $row) return blank value

Tags: php

When I use `array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $row)` before ,the `$row` can normal usage，and use it after，it return a blank value,I've seen the same problem，but still can not solve，here is my code:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `{$table}` LIMIT {$start}, 1000");
foreach ($result as $row) {
   $row = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $row);
   $sql = "INSERT INTO `{$table}` VALUES ('" . implode("', '", $row) . "');\n";
}
```

Comment: (1) are you really just reinserting back into the same table? (2) you are not doing anything with the `$sql`. (3) does `$db->query()` return a result? typically you have to do a `->fetch()`

Comment: (1),yeah,same table.(2)I need print sql,you can think it $sql => $str,(3)$db->query()  return a dyadic array，then use foreach traverse it @Sean

Comment: is `$db` a `mysql` connection (or `mysqli`)?

Comment: @Sean is mysqli,I know what the problem is, the environment has been a problem,but I don't know why,I use other one it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

PHP/mysql alwyas returns the values as strings. This meaans that your call to mysql_real_escape_string will always try to escape a string value.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that you are using `mysqli` to connect to the database and the old `mysql_real_escape_string()` function to escape your values. Since `mysql_real_escape_string` has 2 parameters and you can not pass 2 parameters to a function using the `array_map` function, the second (`$dblink`) parameter tries to use it's default value (last opened mysql connection or there is no open connection it tries to open one using the extension's config). Since you don't have any connections opened and most probably there are no connections defined in your config openinga new connection will fail via the old API.

Try to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` instead.

```
$row = array_map(array($db, 'real_escape_string'), $row);
```

(If you do not use the mysqli extension, but the old mysql, this is the right time to change to the new one, since the old mysql extension is deprecated)

About your queries:
You are using limit without an `ORDER BY` clause. There is no default ordering in MySQL, so the rows returned by your select query is not determined.

Additionally you can do this operation in one query using the `INSERT..SELECT` syntax:

```
INSERT INTO {table}
SELECT * FROM {table} ORDER BY {order_field} LIMIT 1000
```

Note: it is always a good practice to not use *astronomer* queries (stars for astronomers), but list all the columns.

Comment: my db link is use mysqli connect, I try to use '$row = array_map(array($db, 'real_escape_string'), $row);' instead and return a blank array,the key and value is not exists. My ultimate goal is to backup the database , once every thousand take.

Comment: Any error messages? Did you try to debug your query/code line-by-line? What did you find? Your original code's main problem is that the database libraries are different. Did you try the last query which does the job in one step without iterating through the records?